# for each loop in java not working with a array that changes as loop progresses

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

In this I have provided an array of arrays which changes as loop progresses , and the result was not as expected.
Please tell me why that happened.

```
public class forEach2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a [][] = {{ 1,2,3},{4 ,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int proArr = 0;
    for (int pro : a[proArr] ){
        System.out.println(pro);
        proArr ++;
    }

}
```

result -

```
1
2
3
```

here , as the loop starts the value of proArr (which is handling the Array of Arrays , array 'a' to be more specific) changes but that puts no effect o the result.

the result is the data of a[0];

why is this happening in the for loop of Java ?

Comment: It's just the way for-each loops are evaluated. What do you want to accomplish? Print all the numbers? You can do that with two nested loops.

Comment: so do you think it is right , i have incremented the value of proArr and then the loop should work on the second array.

Comment: No, it's not right. What are you trying to do??

Comment: Your code does not in any way, shape or form change the array while the loop progresses. There is actually no code at all, anywhere in the question, that *changes* the array. Your premise is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

You program is doing exactly as you have asked.

```
for ( x in { 1, 2, 3 } )
    echo x
```

You loop a total of thee times, iterating each object in index 0 of the multi dimensional array. What do you expect?

In this example, `proArr` is meaningless after you start the for loop, as the incremented value is never consumed.

If you wish to print the whole multi dimensional array, you must use two nested loops.

```
// Loop super array, getting each nested array
for ( int[] x : a ) {

    // Loop each nested array and print
    for ( int y : x ) {

        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Update to print only first element of each array like OP needs

```
// Loop super array, getting each nested array
for ( int[] x : a ) {

    // Print first element of each
    System.out.println(x[0]);
}
```

Comment: Edited that into my answer just before your comment ;)

Comment: friend i am asking why proArr is meaningless it should not be that. Well its not a way you devoted the question , if people dont know.

Comment: Because you need to loop twice. The first loop will incement the counter for the second loop.

Comment: please print first element of each array with the help of one forEach loop

Comment: `First element of each array` -> Now this is an aspect of the problem that you should have mentioned in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a [][] = {{ 1,2,3},{4 ,5,6},{7,8,9}};
for (int[] pro : a){
    for(int p : pro){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To only first array:

```
for (int pro : a[0]){
    System.out.println(pro);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you wanted to print all values in the multidimensional 'a' array. You need two nested 'for' loops to achieve that.
Change your 'for' loop to this one:

```
for(int [ ] pro : a) {
for(int p : pro){
System.out.println(p);
}
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem :)

**EDIT**

If you want to print only first elements of these arrays you have to change your 'for' loop to this one:

```
for(int [ ] pro : a){
System.out.println(pro[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "please print first element of each array with the help of one forEach
>   loop"

Finally, a definition of the problem! Do this:

```
for (int[] pro : a ){
    System.out.println(pro[0]);
}
```